# Finding the equations of a variety under a projection map

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Suppose I have a projective variety $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^N$ ($N >2$, say) defined as the zero set of some homogeneous polynomials $f_1, \ldots, f_r$. Consider the projection map $[x_0: x_1 : \cdots :x_N] \mapsto [x_0:x_1]$ from $\mathbb{P}^N$ to $\mathbb{P}^1$. How can I find, in general, the defining equations of my variety $X$ under this projection?

To make things more explicit, how can I find the defining equations of $X$ under the above projection for the following toy examples:

- $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^4$ defined by $\mathbb{V}(x_0^2 -  x_1 x_2, x_3^2 +3 x_3 x_4 - x_4^2)$;
- $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^3$ defined by $\mathbb{V}(x_0^2 -  x_1 x_2, x_3^2 + x_0 x_2)$;
- $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^3$ defined by $\mathbb{V}(x_0^2 -  x_1 x_2, x_3^2 +3 x_3 x_2)$.

I'm trying to understand how projections of varieties work, so many details, examples, and explanations are more than welcome!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have time to write a full answer just now, but let me just note that in this case the answer a bit trivial: since you are projecting to $\mathbf{P}^1$, the image will either be a finite set of points or else all of $\mathbf{P}^1$. The first one only happens if $X$ is contained in a union of hyperplanes that contain the vertex $\{x_0=x_1=0\}$ of the projection, which isn't the case for any of your varieties, so they all project onto $\mathbf{P}^1$.

Comment: On the other hand, the general question of finding the equations of a projection is a very interesting one, that goes under the name "elimination theory". You can read about it, for example, in Joe Harris' book on algebraic geometry.

Comment: Thanks Asal. I guess my question is: how can I use the equations of $X$ to obtain the equations of $X$ under the projection? For example, in the first toy example, should I discard the second equation completely? And what happens to the variable $x_2$? I'm just slightly confused about how to get the new equations of the projected variety.

Comment: Dear anon1234, what I tried to say is that in these examples there won't be _any_ equations for the projection. E.g. in the first example: if you choose arbitrary values of $x_0$ and $x_1$, it's easy to see that you can find $x_2,x_3,x_4$ which satisfy the two equations of $X$. That gives you a point of $X$ projecting to your (arbitrary) chosen point of $\mathbf{P}^1$. As I said, for the general theory you can consult Harris' book, or google "elimination theory".